# Proper way to generate counter ID for unique values in a SQL column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
pk_id unq_id content
1     1      foo
2     2      bar
3     1      foo
4     1      foo
5     3      baz
6     2      bar
7     4      qux
```

I am populating a table with known content that can repeat a random number of times.
I want to auto-generate the unq_id column which counts the nth appearance of the unique value in the content column.

I am thinking about some foreign key constraint but not particular sure how to construct this kind of constraint. Searching on the web for a long time without result, I can only ask here.

Could someone shed some light? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more simply done when you query the table, using `row_number()`:

```
select pk_id, content,
       row_number() over (partition by content order by pk_id) as unq_id
from t;
```

You can put this logic in a view.

Actually storing the value in the table requires a bit of work.  If you don't pre-calculate the value, your'll need to use a trigger.

Alternatively, if the data does not change, then you can load into a staging table and use the above query to create the final table.

Comment: I got some particular concerns:
(1) performance concern: this table is huge, it would be around 100GB. View would be costly since everytime when I query the table, it will look at the uique values.
(2) consistency: data will not be deleted/purged, but will be appended on daily basis. In the meantime, I will keep using the table. 
Say I queried the table and some of the data are left in my database RAM buffer, I think those data will be used "first" to build the next query by the optimizer. Could it mess up the unq_id sequence, giving different values when I am staging/updating?

Comment: @aspire1inspire2 . . . The first concern is realistic, but an index on `(content, pk_id)` would be a big help.  The second concern is a non-issue.  Databases guarantee data consistency.